# Wifi Driver or general support for PEAQ S1414 notebook

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I have the PEAQ S1414 as my laptop and I am running Ubuntu on it. It has an integrated network card and I can't see any signs of it getting a wifi signal.

`lspci -vnn | grep Network` gives no output. I have read a lot about drivers and I am slowly getting frustrated because I can't get it to work. I will try to be quick to respond and provide any info you may need.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 14 Feb 2017 18:58 CET +0100

Booted last: 14 Feb 2017 00:00 CET +0100

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 5986:069e Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b720 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0461:4d0f Primax Electronics, Ltd HP Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

snd_soc_rt5670        126976  0
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5670
snd_soc_core          212992  2 snd_soc_rt5670,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform
snd_pcm               106496  8 snd_soc_rt5670,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
wmi                    20480  0

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]> Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.36  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::53:80d2:bfd7:b2d8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13061 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9927 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12364871 (12.3 MB)  TX bytes:1264682 (1.2 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search zyxel.com

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       793     1  0 18:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        USB 10/100 LAN
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8152
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 v1.08.2
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/net/enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       9ae6a9fa-950b-41ff-9afc-a09c51275260
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{5}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   9ae6a9fa-950b-41ff-9afc-a09c51275260 | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.36/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          zyxel.com
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.36
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 3150
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 1800
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       domain_name = zyxel.com
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       expiry = 1487097303
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       host_name = linuxpad
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 3600
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::53:80d2:bfd7:b2d8/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Chai_Latte_Tischlampe]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Chai_Latte_Tischlampe | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Chai_Latte_Tischlampe
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/mayer]] (600 root)
[connection] id=mayer | type=wifi | permissions=user:julian:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=mayer
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/JulianMayer]] (600 root)
[connection] id=JulianMayer | type=wifi | permissions=user:julian:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=JulianMayer
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Schnitzelpalast]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Schnitzelpalast | type=wifi | permissions=user:julian:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Schnitzelpalast
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Vienna (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   12.219839] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[   12.219847] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[   12.578064] r8152 1-2:1.0 eth0: v1.08.2
[   14.084823] r8152 1-2:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: renamed from eth0
[   27.570308] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[   89.113875] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: link becomes ready
[  682.214218] r8152 1-2:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: Rx status -71 (repeated 9 times)
[  683.701034] r8152 1-2:1.0 eth0: v1.08.2
[  684.766551] r8152 1-2:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: renamed from eth0
[  684.800840] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[  687.750194] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: https://tweakers.net/productreview/130923/peaq-pnb-s1414-i0n1s.html <- Please read and try what's suggested right after "Performance onder Linux Mint 17.3".

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci` terminal command.

Comment: Also: `dmesg | grep -i sdio` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @CelticWarrior post the steps from the page as an answer and list the page as a source

Comment: @Jeremy31 I would rather wait for user's confirmation but I might go ahead and do what you suggested because I have the feeling the OP won't be back and the information may help somebody else later on.

Answer (score 1):

[Tweakers.net](http://tweakers.net) extensively tested the PEAQ S1414 notebook and they find out it required a driver for the WiFi. The driver is available and can be compile and installed with the following instructions. In terminal, with an alternative internet connection, do:

```
sudo -s
cd /usr/share
sudo apt-get install git build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu
cd rtl8723bu
make
make install
```

With the driver installed proceed to **blacklist** other potentially conflicting drivers:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Add the following lines and save:

```
blacklist rtl8723au
blacklist r8723au
blacklist rtl8723bu
blacklist r8723bu
```

And finally reboot.

Source: https://tweakers.net/productreview/130923/peaq-pnb-s1414-i0n1s.html

Comment: I do not see a reason to blacklist anything. And the driver should be re-installed after each kernel upgrade, unless installed with DKMS.

Comment: You're right, I don't see a reason either, after looking closely but that's in their page. Do you suggest removing that part?

Comment: Let's ask OP to post output of `usb-devices | awk '/0bda/' RS=` and we'll see.

Comment: That's exactly why I was waiting for user input and commented that above to Jeremy before composing the answer.