# No Wifi on Lubuntu (PEAQ)

Tags: drivers, wireless, lubuntu

I installed lubuntu 19.04 on a PEAQ PNB C1014 and i am getting no Wifi signal. 
Can someone please help? 
Should I install a driver? And how? 
Thanks a lot!

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 0c
       serial: b0:25:aa:0d:03:47
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0604000-d0604fff memory:d0600000-d0603fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:4.4
       logical name: wlx8c18d9e3fa1c
       serial: 8c:18:d9:e3:fa:1c
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxu driverversion=5.0.0-13-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.




02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
        Subsystem: Tongfang Hongkong Limited RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
        I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
        Memory at d0604000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Memory at d0600000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
```

Comment: You'll need to provide additional info about the wireless hardware. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883332/wifi-driver-or-general-support-for-peaq-s1414-notebook).

Comment: i added the additional info to the question. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Thanks, that is a good start, and the info shows there is a Realtek wireless card of some kind. To see its model, try `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 0280`, and also add the output of `rfkill list`.

Comment: Let's also see: `lsusb` I suspect that rtl8xxxu is not the correct driver for your device. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @mikewhatever Hi, I'm fairly new to ubutnu:
So first I type lshw -C network in terminal and then I add lspci -nnk | grep -A3 0280? Cause nothing happens...
Thanks!

Comment: lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b720 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:053a Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0581:0105 Racal Data Group 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Looks like you have another RTL8723bu https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182671/no-wifi-on-lubuntu-peaq?noredirect=1#comment1976267_1182671